# Как правильно сделать колоду из карт, хранящихся в таблице?

Tags: python, база-данных, ооп

Итак у меня есть база данных вида
[image: таблица cards]

Далее я получаю любую карту типа tuple из бд с помощью метода:

```
def get_card_by_id(id):
    cur = db_bj.cursor()
    result = cur.execute(
        f'SELECT value,card_suit,sticker_id FROM cards WHERE id="{id}"').fetchone() 
    print(result)
    return result
```

после этого хочу создать колоду используя namedtuple

```
from utils.db_api.handler import get_card_by_id

Card = namedtuple('Card', ['value', 'card_suit', 'sticker_id'])
new_deck = []
for i in range(0, 14):
    id = i
    card = get_card_by_id(id)
    value = card[0]
    card_suit = card[1]
    sticker_id = card[2]
    Card = Card(value, card_suit, sticker_id)
    new_deck.append(Card)
    print(new_deck)
```

но упираюсь в то, что не могу понять как надо это сделать правильно, чтобы потом поместить карты в класс Deck

```
class Deck(object):
    new_deck = []

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.cards = []
        self.refresh_deck()

    def refresh_deck(self) -> int:
        self.cards = list(map(Card, self.new_deck))

    def shuffle(self) -> None:
        shuffle(self.cards)

    def draw_card(self) -> Card:
        return self.cards.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде того? Без доступа к Бд сложновато

```
def create_deck():
    new_deck = []
    for i in range(0, 14):
        id = i
        card = get_card_by_id(id)
        value = card[0]
        card_suit = card[1]
        sticker_id = card[2]
        Card = Card(value, card_suit, sticker_id)
        new_deck.append(Card)
        print(new_deck)
    return new_deck

deck = Deck()
deck.cards.append(create_deck())
```